# Getting downvoted on correct answers?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I recently gave a **correct** answer, I can tell as I have done research and even added images to the answer. Yet it still got 1 *(strategical?)* downvote.

I surely don't want to remove the answer as I think it will be useful to the one who asked the question. Is there a way I can deal with this, and what would you consider the best way?

Comment: Yes - you move on. (And BTW you know these are 2 tiny rep points we are talking about, right?)

Comment: Nevermind dude you don't get my point, you move on. It's not that I mind the rep points, but I'm just wondering what is the correct way to deal with this, should I ignore it, should I comment on it, should I remove my answer, or what other possibilities are there?

Comment: As I said - ignore it. If your answer is good you will probably get upvotes in the future anyway.

Comment: @DaanHeskes, you're appealing to humans (presumably). The only way to have an infallible arbiter of truth, is to bring about the Singularity.

Comment: You're probably not even appealing to a human. You're shouting into the ether at someone who's not going to come back to read your comments or check if you've fixed the problem they perceived in your answer because there's no good way for them to be notified of the comments or your edit.

Comment: There can be many different personal reasons for downvotes. Not saying this applies to your answer, but in the last few days, I've downvoted "lazy" answers (e.g. code dump a la "try this" without explanations) on bad, unresearched and unclear questions. I feel these answerers are either trying to grab some easy rep or act out of a false sense of "being helpful", but show a complete disregard to educating OP on the topic at hand, and more importantly on the rules and expected behaviour on SO, which is in my opinion more harmful than helpful.

Comment: Posting a link to the answer will help to give more detail on the possible reason for the downvote.

Comment: Regarding Linking the answer: Just be aware of the meta-effect. There'll be a spotlight on your answer and many who ordinarily wouldn't bother / see it might comment / flag / downvote / (sometimes even upvote).

Comment: I'm guessing this post is about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23561239/1906307). It is the OP's most recent answer and has a downvote.

Comment: @Deduplicator: If you are afraid of Meta visitors downvoting, the answer probably wasn't that good that you are confident about it.

Comment: @Louis: If it is about that answer, even the OP isn't confident it is a good answer...

Comment: Tbh, you don't answer the question, you basically say the question is nonsense, which could easily be done in a comment (with a close flag too)

Comment: define "correct answer" cause as far as I know there can be many correct answers. You didnt even provide an example. Maybe someone was more experienced than you or didn't think your answer was that useful. I see idiotic answers given to questions all the time, do I downvote them? Yes if they are pretty bad. Sometimes they are even upvotes on them but if you personally know better and have the ability to vote, you do. No hard feelings, ignore and move on if there is no comment explaining the downvote...

Answer (score 13):

If you are certain that your answer is good, just let it be. As you say, you don't mind the rep points, so all that matters is the fact that there is good and correct content for the site.

However, don't fully ignore the downvotes. They might be indicating a problem with your answer. No matter how convinced you are of its correctness, perhaps you've overlooked something. Or maybe you didn't, but you did not explain clearly enough how your answer addresses the problem.

In the worst case you can leave a comment along the lines of *"The downvotes seem to indicate a problem with this answer. Is there anything I can do to address this?"*. If someone wishes to reply to that, they could. Don't however ask for a direct explanation from the downvoters. Always keep focused on you addressing any problems with your content, instead of demanding a justification.

Overall, if the content is good, you'll get your recognition eventually.